# In Sybase SUP, do you have suggestions for non-example startup?

Tags: sup

All,

Maybe I'm thinking too much about this.  All of the examples I have seen seem to cover starting a (iOS) native App from the AppDelegate.  I'm not excited about this, but I can't get around it so that it feels more comfortable.  Are you doing something different, and how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply move the processing of initializing the SUP connection from the AppDelegate's applicationDidFinishLaunching method to the viewDidLoad method of your main view controller class.

You would also need to move the NotificationCenter handler methods to your main view controller class.